# How to deal answer, that officially not recommended but only possible way of problem

Tags: discussion

I want to know how to deal right answer of question that not recommended by officially but it best solution of user requirement. And a expert guy come say see this this answer not recommended by officially and negative marking on answer without understand problem.

What we have to do with that answer ???

Comment: Are you talking about your own answer that you are writing, or are you talking about how to moderate someone else's answer on SO?

Comment: How can you both be an expert and not understand the problem at the same time?

Comment: Could you be more specific (e.g. link to the answer you're referring to)? *Why* does the *"expert guy"* say it's not recommended, and is that concern relevant to the use case?

Comment: Its only for example please do not vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I assume you mean what to do with [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581255/dialogfragment-created-twice-after-orientation-change/26709740#26709740) now. Seeing how this answer does answer the question, I think you should keep it. You can however note that one of the other answers might be a better solution to the problem and add extra details to why your answer might come in handy after all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I get 1 one down vote on that qu. I want keep that answer but no more down vote. So I am requesting you please remove my ans link

Comment: And friend my ans is accepted because it work for asker. Thats why I am saying it best solution of that question